# What is the return type of TextView.getText() in android?

Tags: android, xml, textview, charsequence

Why does `TextView.getText()` return a `CharSequence` instead of a `String`?
(String is the implementation of the CharSequence)

Comment: why is this a bad question?

Comment: most likely because it's explained in the dev docs, and as such there isn't a huge need to ask here. That's just a guess.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it might contain a `Spannable` object. From the doc:

> If `setText()` was called with an argument of `BufferType.SPANNABLE` or
>   `BufferType.EDITABLE`, you can cast the return value from this method to
>   `Spannable` or `Editable`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

it actually returns `Editable` and not `CharSequence` but you can store it in a String variable by calling `toString()` on it.