# why we are getText().toString()

Tags: android

I am new to programming can any tell why we are converting gettext().tostring and what is interger.ParseInt, if you want to tell any other things for converting which can be help in programming, please let me no

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, unfortunately your question does not demonstrate any attempt of prior research. In order to get a good response, it is advised you should show evidence you have attempted to solve the problem, either in code or otherwise, before asking a question. May I suggest reading the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) and [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android TextView.getText() return type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915797/android-textview-gettext-return-type)

Answer (score 2):

### getText()

When you are calling [`getText()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()) you are getting back a **[CharSequence](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/CharSequence.html)**, so you use [`toString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) to convert the CharSequence into a **[String](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html)**

### parseInt()

**[Integer.parseInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))** helps you to convert a String to an **[Integer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html)**

Here an example

```
String numberToConvert = "1";
Integer convertedNumber = Integer.parseInt(numberToConvert);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `getText()` returns `CharSequence` and you can not use it like a string if you don't convert it first, that's why we write `toString()` after the `getText()` method. Take a look at the documentation here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()

Integer is a  wrapper of the primitive type `int`, which actually represents a number without a floating point (no matter if positive or negative). Take a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html